# Time averages for a 2-dimensional harmonic oscillator

Tags: self-learning, classical-mechanics, average, ergodic-theory

I'm studying Ergodic Theory and I think I "got" the concept, but I need an example to verify it.

Let's take the simplest possible 2D classical harmonic oscillator whose kinetic energy is $$T=\frac{\dot x^2}{2}+\frac{\dot y^2}{2}$$ and potential energy is $$U=\frac{ x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}$$

Could you show me the time averages of those two quantities?

Comment: The expression for the time average of a quantity is the same for any quantity. The problem is that the kinetic and potential energies of the 2-dimensional harmonic oscillator are not what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you @JohnB but the same example could be found in _Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics_ by V. I. Arnol'd, page 289

Comment: Understood, that's what you mean then by "2D", namely that it is 4D. Great, now you just take the average.

Comment: So @JohnB you mean to just pass to polar coordinates, then average, which would give $\langle Kinetic \rangle = \langle Potential \rangle = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: I was always talking about the "expression for the time average of a quantity". Without more information you won't be able to obtain explicit values.

Comment: You're right, I've (unbelievably) forgotten to say that all parameters - oscillation amplitudes, mass, spring constant, etc - are unitary in value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the amplitudes are unitary we have
$$
(x(t),y(t))=(\cos(t+c),\cos(t+d))
$$
for some $c,d\in\mathbb R$ and all $t$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
\langle U\rangle
&=\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\frac1\tau\int_0^\tau\frac12(x(t)^2+y(t)^2)\,dt\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12(x(t)^2+y(t)^2)\,dt\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12(\cos^2(t+c)+\cos^2(t+d))\,dt=\frac12,
\end{split}
$$
after some simple computations, since
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(t+c)\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(t+d)\,dt=\pi.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
\begin{split}
\langle T\rangle
&=\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\frac1\tau\int_0^\tau\frac12(\dot x(t)^2+\dot y(t)^2)\,dt\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12(\dot x(t)^2+\dot y(t)^2)\,dt=\frac12.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I don't want to bother and I warmly welcome your answer, but isn't $\langle T \rangle = \langle U \rangle = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @LoScrondo Indeed, corrected right now.

Comment: Oh fine! I was yet asking myself where I could have mistaken a so simple calculation :-)...many thanks and obligations for your time!!

Comment: @LoScrondo You're welcome. It's easy to make mistakes when one writes "after some simple computations"...